# stack run in multi package project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Is there a way to specify which executable to run (with `stack run`) when I am working with a Stack [multi package project](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#multi-package-projects)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was using the package name rather than the executable name in my `stack run` command:

- Wrong: `stack run foo`
- Correct: `stack run foo-exe`